# Google play Does not search my app do any optimisation needed

Tags: android

Google play Does not search my app do any optimisation needed.
My app name is Xmas Catch   and package name is com.xmascatch
when i search by xmascatch it searchs well but when i search by Xmas Catch it doesnt show my app
Help me please....

Answer (score 1):

When did you add the application? Google needs more than 12 hours to update its search index. There is even a difference between the search indexes in different countries and different languages. You have to be patient.

Comment: I have added it before 10 days